# systemd service with multiple After

Tags: linux, service, systemd

Is it possible to create a service that depends on several other services? What is the right syntax?

Such as:

```
[Unit]
Description=service description
Wants=network.target
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=bootapp
ExecStart=/var/app/app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The goal is to start a service automatically after OS reboot and make sure that logging and networking services are started prior to the service.

Additional question: Do I need to specify `Restart`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The unit file you posted looks fine. But the unit as you defined it here has no strict dependencies, only weak (`Wants=` instead of `Requires=`). That means if network.target is not there or if it fails to start, this unit would be started anyway. `After=` (and `Before=`) is used only for ordering, not for dependency management. So if your app **needs** another service, use `Requires=`. If it needs that service **before** it can be started itself, use `After=` additionally.

To enable your unit to start automatically after booting, you have to enable it. Systemd needs to know where to link it for starting, that's what `WantedBy=` in the `[Install]` section is used for. After editing the unit file and saving it in `/etc/systemd/system/my-unit.service` you have to reload the systemd daemon to have it pick up the new unit, before you can enable it; the command is `systemctl daemon-reload`. To enable the unit type `systemctl enable my-unit.service`. This adds a symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` to your unit file.

To start it manually you can type `systemctl start my-unit.service`.

`Restart=` is only needed if you want your app to be automatically restarted, when it exited. There are different possibilities for when to restart, like `on-failure` or `always` (more in the man page of `systemd.service`).

Also your app.jar needs to be executable for this to work. If it is and it starts your app, then it's fine. I think a jar must be started by sth. like `java -jar app.jar`, but ofc. I could be wrong here.